# NFTs minted from mainnet but not showing on Opensea or Rarible

Tags: nft

Here's my Remix contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
// Amended by HashLips

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {   using Strings for uint256;

    string public baseURI;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    string public notRevealedUri;
    uint256 public cost = 0.05 ether;
    uint256 public maxSupply = 500;
    uint256 public nftPerAddressLimit = 5;

    mapping(address => uint256) public mintedWallets;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI,
        string memory _initNotRevealedUri   ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
        setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);   }

        function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require(msg.value == cost, "Wrong Eth Price");
        require(_mintAmount > 0, "Need to Mint at least 1 NFT");
        require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, "Max NFT limit exceeded");
        require(mintedWallets[msg.sender] <= 5, "Cannot Mint more than 5 NFTs from one Wallet");
        uint256 ownerMintedCount = mintedWallets[msg.sender];
        require(ownerMintedCount + _mintAmount <= nftPerAddressLimit, "Cannot Mint more than 5 NFTs from one Wallet");

        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
            mintedWallets[msg.sender]++;
            _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + i);
        }  
    }

    function walletOfOwner(address _owner) public view returns (uint256[] memory)   {
        uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
        for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokenIds;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory)   {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension)): "";
    }

    function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        cost = _newCost;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension) public onlyOwner {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }

    function setNotRevealedURI(string memory _notRevealedURI) public onlyOwner {
        notRevealedUri = _notRevealedURI;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        (bool hs, ) = payable(xxx).call{value: address(this).balance * 5 / 100}("");
        require(hs);

        (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(os);
    }
}
```

Now strange thing that I find is if I mint Nfts using Mumbai Testnet, it mints and I can see them on OpenSea testnet, but if I use BSC testnet it doesn't mint saying price is wrong which I don't know where it's getting from because I am putting the correct amount. And if I use Ropsten testnet it mints but nothing shows up on Opensea testnet like it doesn't even increases the number of NFTs on Opensea testnet profile.
And I have used the same contract on my website to fully test minting from mainnnet and it does mints but nothing shows up on opensea or rarible mainnet, says: No Item Found.

I don't even know what I'm doing wrong, opensea and rarible doesn't give any errors or warnings

Comment: If it works in a testnet then the contract is fine. So my guess is that it is a problem with the markets. What's the token address? Did you contact their customer support?

Comment: Thanks for the respond, it was my dumbness, first time trying any of this, figured that I have to deploy contract on mainnet for nft to show on opensea mainnet